# If someone is appointed to a committee, is that member allowed to vote in the same meeting?

Tags: roberts-rules-of-order

If a committee appoints a member to itself, is that newly appointed member allowed to vote in the same meeting he/she is elected or must the meeting be adjourned before that right is granted?

Comment: May or may not be relevant (both under Roberts Rules and any organization-specific bylaws), but "appointment" and "election" are normally two distinct actions and so they may have different results.

Answer (score 9):

First, there are many versions of Robert's Rules of Order: [here](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/9097/pg9097-images.html#art06) is an early free version. §26(c) suggests a procedure for creation of a committee to draft resolutions, and §53 contemplates other (standing) committees. Nothing therein suggests that there are restrictions on the right of a member to vote, in terms of a mandatory adjournment. However, RRO is not a Universal Organizational Bylaws, so in order to have any force, it must be adopted as part of the bylaws (in whole or part). It especially cannot dictate who is eligible to vote – that is a detail that has to be in the organization's bylaws.

Comment: It should be pointed out that Roberts Rules is guidelines for parliamentary procedure for non-legislative bodies modeled after U.S. Congress and while commonly used in the U.S. for such bodies, it is not as popularly used outside of its home country given that U.S. Congress might have different parliamentary procedures from other nations.